# Check $row for value and amend

Tags: php

I am using flexigrid for displaying data and need help to check a row for a value and change it. The data is being returned to flexigrid via json and works well and without ant errors. however, what I am trying to do is check the row; $row['status'] for a value = 1 and if that row is that value then change it to value = "In".

I have tried various ways to code using an if statement, but it does not error, just dosen't display the data in the grid. What is the correct way to code this row? Thanks

```
$results = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
$data['rows'][] = array(
'id' => $row['Id'],
'cell' => array($row['Id'], $row['rack'].$row['column'].'-'.$row['row'].'-'.$row['bay'], $row['customer'], $dropdown, $service, $row['department'], if ($row['status']==1){$row['status']="In"}, $row['custref'], $row['size'], $row['authorisation'], date('d/m/Y H:m:s',strtotime($row['intake_date'])), date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['destroy_date']))));
}
echo $json->encode($data);
```

Comment: Where is your `$row['status']` check code ? Please post that too to help you in finding the issue in it.

Comment: @Rikesh what do you mean by check code, you mean the if statement? Thanks

Comment: Yes. The if statement. We can't see it in above code.

Comment: @Rikesh added in original code. Thanks